# How to check if a value in this is a prototype value in javascript?

Tags: javascript, object, prototype

I've got the following code:

```
function test() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
}

test.prototype.b = 10;
test.prototype.c = 12;

var example = new test();
```

How do I find out if `example.something`:

**A.** has only a value in the function object?

**B.** has only a value in the prototype?

**C.** has a value in both the function object and prototype?

Comment: "has only a value in the function object?" --- what does it mean?

Comment: If with the *function object* you mean *example*, then that is quite a misleading term. the only function (object) is *test*.

Comment: I mean test. The answers with above example should be: A: example.a, B: example.c, C: example.b. But how do I determine that with js code?

Comment: You can use [*hasOwnProperty*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/7.0/index.html#sec-hasownproperty) to see if a property is on an object. If it has the property but it's not an own property, it must be inherited.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can test the prototype to see if the value is specified in the prototype with this:

```
example.constructor.prototype.b
```

or

```
Object.getPrototypeOf(example).b
```

You can test if the property is directly on the object itself (e.g. not inherited or on the direct prototype) with:

```
example.hasOwnProperty("b")
```

Comment: Thanks this is exactly what I needed!

Answer (score 1):

You can check the properties within the object and its prototype by using the `Object.keys` method.

```js
function test() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
}

test.prototype.b = 10;
test.prototype.c = 12;

var example = new test();

console.log(Object.keys(example));
console.log(Object.keys(example.__proto__));
```

Comment: Objects can inherit from more than one prototype, e.g. *toString* is typically inherited from *Object.prototype*, not the constructor's *prototype*.

Answer (score 1):

This code reveals this:

```js
function test() {
    this.a = 5;
    this.b = 6;
}

test.prototype.b = 10;
test.prototype.c = 12;

var example = new test();

for (prop of ['a', 'b', 'c']) {
    if (example.hasOwnProperty(prop)) console.log(prop + ' is owned by the object');
    if (test.prototype.hasOwnProperty(prop)) console.log(prop + ' is owned by the object prototype');
}
```